# Dynamic markers not working using new variable

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, dynamic, google-maps-markers

```
var latitude = document.getElementById("latitude");
var longitude = document.getElementById("longitude");

var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
var marker;

function initialize()
{
    var mapProp = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

`var latitude` didn't get the values

here I get the values from below ids,

```
<div class="map" id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:260px;overflow:hidden;"></div>
<div id="latitude"><?php echo $itemData['130']; ?></div>
<div id="longitude"><?php echo $itemData['131']; ?></div>
```

In `$itemData['130']` and `$itemData['130']` gets the value fine,

I don't know what's the mistake I done?

Comment: Is this script placed in the head or in the body? When it's placed in the head, move the first 3 lines of your code to the begin of initialize. And remove the last line.

Comment: Then do the suggested modifications, currently both elements are unknown when you try to access them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
This code will work try this

function initialize() {
var latitude = document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML;
var longitude = document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML;
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
var marker;
var mapProp = {
center: myCenter,
zoom: 16,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myCenter,
animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
});
marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your getting the object. Use `.innerHTML` if you want that value that is being echoed by PHP:

```
var latitude = document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to get the contents of the HTML div elements after the DOM has been rendered (inside your initialize function)
2. document.getElementById returns an HTML element, you need the text content (I use a `nodeValue` function from [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) to get that, but similar functionality is available in JQuery and other libraries).

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwj2c84z/)

code snippet:

```js
var marker;

function initialize()
{
var latitude = nodeValue(document.getElementById("latitude"));
var longitude = nodeValue(document.getElementById("longitude"));

var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var mapProp = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
//nodeValue: Extract the text value of a DOM node, with leading and trailing whitespace trimmed
var nodeValue = function(node, defVal) {
  var retStr="";
  if (!node) {
    return (typeof defVal === 'undefined' || defVal === null) ? '' : defVal;
  }
   if(node.nodeType==3||node.nodeType==4||node.nodeType==2){
      retStr+=node.nodeValue;
   }else if(node.nodeType==1||node.nodeType==9||node.nodeType==11){
      for(var i=0;i<node.childNodes.length;++i){
         retStr+=arguments.callee(node.childNodes[i]);
      }
   }
   return retStr;
};
```

```css
html, body, #googleMap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="latitude">45</div>
<div id="longitude">-85</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
var latitude = document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML;
var longitude = document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML;
```

Note: This one will result the lattitude and longitude. The one you used will produce the object not the value.

Comment: sorry I need to get the values from both ids

Comment: Yes and the above one will output value from both the IDs. But the one you used will output the object, not the values.

Comment: how to get the values

Comment: This is the code to get the value for lattitude `document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML` and check above code to get the longitude.